# Finding IDLE/Inactive users on server

Tags: batch-file, cmd, server

I have the command below that when run through cmd will find out the users logged on to a server(has to be run as admin).

```
query user /server:Server1
```

This returns all users who are logged on to the server. I would like the command to return to me only inactive users/users who have been logged in longer than a day on the server. How would I go about doing this?

Thanks in advance,

SG

Comment: and you want to use `logon time` to filter the users?

Comment: How would I go about adding that filter? Tried it on the end as well with a / but cant do it? I tried the filter /? to find filters regarding id but they only have session name session id and username?